# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance() not working in IE 10

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, internet-explorer-10, pagerequestmanager

I am facing some asp.net ajax problem in my application on IE 10. But it is running correctly in compatibility mode of IE 10.

on my page i am registering this event in update panel :-

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function() {
   //my code here
});
```

this code is working fine in all other browser

Please help me. Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think [this fix from microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088) will help or you can add folder app_browsers in your project and create ie.browser file.